# What do these arguments refer to?

Tags: python, urllib2

In the method of the class `urllib2.HTTPDefaultErrorHandler` what so the arguments - `self`, `req`, `fp`, `code`,`msg`, `hdrs` - refer to?

Comment: If you're asking about `self` you should probably sit down with an introductory python book before trying to look at library source code

Answer (score 3):

What does [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) say?

`req` will be a Request object, `fp` will be a file-like object with the HTTP error body, `code` will be the three-digit code of the error, `msg` will be the user-visible explanation of the code and `hdrs` will be a mapping object with the headers of the error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Req refers to request object usually contains HTTP method and url
2. code refers to response code or HTTP code value like 200 etc
3. hdr refers to headers of the request like user-agent etc
4. fp refers to file descriptor or socket descriptor in this case